# How do I repeat the same regex pattern for an unspecified number of key value pairs

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tried writing a regular expression to extract an unspecified amount of key value pairs split by equals (excluding quotes)

```
/^EVENTS?(\s([A-Z]+)=("([^"]*)"|([^"\s]+)))+$/gm
```

Here are the lines that it should be processing:

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>FORM>DIV>INPUT" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEDOWN SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV" BUTTON=2
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEDOWN SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV" BUTTON=1
EVENTS TYPE=MOUSEMOVE SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV" POINTS="(813,214),(809,213)"
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEUP POINT="(1329,221)"
```

It only seems to capture the **last** key value pair only, not the ones before it. I've tried wrapping it in another capture group, but that doesn't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know maximum repeatation of key value, just repeat your key value pattern as following.

```js
const value = `EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>FORM>DIV>INPUT" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEDOWN SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV" BUTTON=2
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEDOWN SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV" BUTTON=1
EVENTS TYPE=MOUSEMOVE SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV" POINTS="(813,214),(809,213)"
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEUP POINT="(1329,221)"`
const repeatCount = 3;
const pat = new RegExp('^EVENTS?' + '(?:\\s([A-Z]+)=("(?:[^"]*)"|(?:[^"\\s]+)))?'.repeat(repeatCount) + '$', 'gm')
const ret = [...value.matchAll(pat)].map(item => item.filter((value, index) => !!value && index > 0))
console.log(JSON.stringify(ret, null, 4))
```

Result:

```json
[
    [
        "TYPE",
        "CLICK",
        "SELECTOR",
        "\"HTML>BODY>FORM>DIV>INPUT\"",
        "BUTTON",
        "0"
    ],
    [
        "TYPE",
        "MOUSEDOWN",
        "SELECTOR",
        "\"HTML>BODY>DIV\"",
        "BUTTON",
        "2"
    ],
    [
        "TYPE",
        "MOUSEDOWN",
        "SELECTOR",
        "\"HTML>BODY>DIV\"",
        "BUTTON",
        "1"
    ],
    [
        "TYPE",
        "MOUSEMOVE",
        "SELECTOR",
        "\"HTML>BODY>DIV\"",
        "POINTS",
        "\"(813,214),(809,213)\""
    ],
    [
        "TYPE",
        "MOUSEUP",
        "POINT",
        "\"(1329,221)\""
    ]
]
```

I just modified your pattern by dividing starting part(`^EVENTS?`), repeating part(`\s([A-Z]+)=("([^"]*)"|([^"\s]+))`) and ending part(`$`).

And some modification in repeating part is

1. Inserted `?:` for none capture group.
2. Appended `?` for less repeated line than specified.

And also I removed undefined value (for less repeated line) and first item (whole matched value) by filtering with `!!value && index > 0`

---

But I suggest you to ignore starting `EVENT(S)` string.

Because there's no way to get your result with one pattern as I think.

If you give up starting `EVENT(S)`, solution is very simple as following.

```js
const value = `EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>FORM>DIV>INPUT" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEDOWN SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV" BUTTON=2
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEDOWN SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV" BUTTON=1
EVENTS TYPE=MOUSEMOVE SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV" POINTS="(813,214),(809,213)"
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEUP POINT="(1329,221)"`
const ret = [...value.matchAll(/\s([A-Z]+)=("([^"]*)"|([^"\s]+))/g)].map(([all, key, value]) => [ key, value ])
console.log(JSON.stringify(ret, null, 2))
```

Result:

```json
[
  [
    "TYPE",
    "CLICK"
  ],
  [
    "SELECTOR",
    "\"HTML>BODY>FORM>DIV>INPUT\""
  ],
  [
    "BUTTON",
    "0"
  ],
  [
    "TYPE",
    "MOUSEDOWN"
  ],
  [
    "SELECTOR",
    "\"HTML>BODY>DIV\""
  ],
  [
    "BUTTON",
    "2"
  ],
  [
    "TYPE",
    "MOUSEDOWN"
  ],
  [
    "SELECTOR",
    "\"HTML>BODY>DIV\""
  ],
  [
    "BUTTON",
    "1"
  ],
  [
    "TYPE",
    "MOUSEMOVE"
  ],
  [
    "SELECTOR",
    "\"HTML>BODY>DIV\""
  ],
  [
    "POINTS",
    "\"(813,214),(809,213)\""
  ],
  [
    "TYPE",
    "MOUSEUP"
  ],
  [
    "POINT",
    "\"(1329,221)\""
  ]
]
```

I just modified your pattern by removing `^EVENTS?` for starting `EVENT(S)`, `(` and `)+` for repeated finding, `$` for end of line, `m` option from `/^EVENTS?(\s([A-Z]+)=("([^"]*)"|([^"\s]+)))+$/gm`

Answer (score 0):

When using Regex methods be sure to know what they return and what they do after a match is found. A match isn't always what you need so groups are crucial. `.matchAll()` will return an array containing an array for every hit if you apply the spread operator: `...` and put it in an empty array `[]`:

```
 [...string.matchAll(regex)]
 // [[MATCH, GROUP1, GROUP2,...GROUPN], ...[...]]
```

So in your case every hit involves 2 capturing groups but not the match because it'll have everything, for example in your results a match will look like this:

```
  POINTS=\"(813,214),(809,213)
```

Use an array method to extract the second `sub[1]` and third `sub[2]` values from each sub-array. In the example below, `.flatMap()` was used.

```
   sub[1] = "POINTS" sub[2] = "(813,214),(809,213)"
```

```js
const data = `EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>FORM>DIV>INPUT" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEDOWN SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV" BUTTON=2
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEDOWN SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV" BUTTON=1
EVENTS TYPE=MOUSEMOVE SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV" POINTS="(813,214),(809,213)"
EVENT TYPE=MOUSEUP POINT="(1329,221)"`;

const findKV = str => {
  const rgx = new RegExp(/\b([A-Z]+)\b="*([A-Z0-9>(,)]+)/, 'g');
  return [...str.matchAll(rgx)].flatMap((sub, idx) => {
    return [idx + ': Key: ' + sub[1] + ' / Value: ' + sub[2]]
  });
};

console.log(findKV(data));
```